# Leaflet Time Series

Tags: leaflet, time-series

I am trying to create a code using leaflet and am having trouble animating a series of weather radar images using WMS. My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.js">

    </script>

    <div id="map" style='width: 943px; height: 480px;'></div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.control.min.css"
    />

</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js">

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nezasa/iso8601-js-period/master/iso8601.min.js">

    </script>

    <script>
        //make the map

      var wmsLayerRadarRrai4kmLink = 'https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?'

      var wmsLayerRadarRrai4km = L.tileLayer.wms(wmsLayerRadarRrai4kmLink, {
        layers: 'RADAR_RRAI',
        version: '1.1.0',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
        //opacity: .75
      });

      var wmsLayerRadarRrai4kmTD = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(wmsLayerRadarRrai4km, {
      });

      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [49.9, -97.215],
        zoom: 5,
        fullScreenControl: true,
        timeDimension: true,
        timeDimensionControl: true,
        timeDimensionOptions: {
        },
        timeDimensionControlOptions: {
          autoPlay: true, 
          playerOptions: {
          loop: true,
          timeSteps: 1,
          }
        }
      });

      //get the wms layers



      var proxy = 'server/proxy.php'



      //group wms layers

      var overlayMaps = {
        "Radar Rain 4km": wmsLayerRadarRrai4kmTD
      };

    //get basemaps using tileLayer

      var basemapDark =  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}  {r}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy;<a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
          subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 19
      });

      var basemapLight = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 19,
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      });

      //group basemaps

      var baseMaps = {
        "Light": basemapLight,
        "Dark": basemapDark
      };

      L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

      L.control.timeDimension
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The initial default layer will load, but once the time layer is enables/played, nothing else displays. It appears to be grabbing the correct time component from the GetCapabilities, so I am not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like like Leaflet TimeDimension plugin and https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet WMS service do not go very well along together.

TimeDimension plugin uses `getCapabilities` call to get time series from WMS service. Response has hefty 14MB. Plugin analyzes this response to get times for time series calls to WMS service (`time` parameter).

Obviously something goes wrong in this analysis. I checked time series calls in debugger and all return status `500 - Internal server error`. Example of one such call:

```
https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=RADAR_RRAI&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.0&time=2019-05-07T14%3A20%3A00.000Z&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=-11271098.44281895,6261721.357121641,-10018754.171394622,7514065.628545967
```

Time in this call is `2019-05-07T14:20:00.000Z`.

I checked `getCapabilities` response and chosen one of the times I found there. Time was `2019-05-07T17:00:00Z`. With this time I got valid response.

**EDIT:** Some further research showed that the only problem is in time format passed to WMS service. TimeDimension plugin uses ISO-8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, but WMS service expects time without hundreds of seconds `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`.

Since TimeDimension plugin offers no option or method to format time, the only solution is to override method `_createLayerForTime` of `L.TimeDimension.Layer.WMS` object, which prepares WMS request:

```
L.TimeDimension.Layer.WMS.include({
  _createLayerForTime: function(time){
      var wmsParams = this._baseLayer.options;
      // original 
      // wmsParams.time = new Date(time).toISOString();
      // hacked
      wmsParams.time = new Date(time).toISOString().slice(0, 19)+'Z';
      return new this._baseLayer.constructor(this._baseLayer.getURL(), wmsParams);
  }
});
```

The whole code would then look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.control.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nezasa/iso8601-js-period/master/iso8601.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" style='width: 943px; height: 480px;'></div>
    <script>
      L.TimeDimension.Layer.WMS.include({
        _createLayerForTime: function(time){
            var wmsParams = this._baseLayer.options;
            wmsParams.time = new Date(time).toISOString().slice(0, 19)+'Z';
            return new this._baseLayer.constructor(this._baseLayer.getURL(), wmsParams);
        }
      });

      var wmsLayerRadarRrai4kmLink = 'https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?'

      var wmsLayerRadarRrai4km = L.tileLayer.wms(wmsLayerRadarRrai4kmLink, {
        layers: 'RADAR_RRAI',
        version: '1.3.0',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
      });

      var wmsLayerRadarRrai4kmTD = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(wmsLayerRadarRrai4km, {
      });

      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [49.9, -97.215],
        zoom: 5,
        fullScreenControl: true,
        timeDimension: true,
        timeDimensionControl: true,
        timeDimensionOptions: {
        },
        timeDimensionControlOptions: {
          autoPlay: false, 
          playerOptions: {
          loop: false,
          timeSteps: 1,
          }
        }
      });

      var overlayMaps = {
        "Radar Rain 4km": wmsLayerRadarRrai4kmTD
      };

      var basemapDark =  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}  {r}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy;<a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
          subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 19
      });

      var basemapLight = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 19,
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      });

      var baseMaps = {
        "Light": basemapLight,
        "Dark": basemapDark
      };

      L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
      L.control.timeDimension;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been going at this for quite some time now and could not figure out the issue. The issue with the **TimeDimension** plugin could be narrowed down by loading a number of radar images into their own variables and animate that way. Is there a way to get the most recent time associated with the radar image in order to perform a time-specific image search under the `L.tileLayer.wms(layer, {time: });` option? I would like to plug the latest time associated with the image and store in a `var` to use there and subtract 10min from that `var` to get the next param.

Comment: See my modified answer for solution.